# What is this exclamation mark menu item?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When I opened CS:GO today, this exclamation mark menu item appeared which wasn't there before.  Nothing happens when I click on it.

What exactly is it and why did it suddenly appear?

[image: screenshot showing the mysterious exclamation mark]

Comment: If I had to guess, you have 1 pending notification. Maybe a drop?

Comment: @badp Wouldn't be a drop. Notifications for those show up underneath the inventory tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an alert for the newest gameplay fix in the [latest patch:](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2014/09/10228/)

> - The CZ75-Auto has been moved from the P250 slot to the Tec9/Five-seveN slot and its price has been raised to $500.

[image]

Comment: It's now vanished for me, but thank you for satisfying my curiosity.